# What is the correct Java main() method parameters syntax?

Tags: java, syntax

Is there a functional difference between these methods?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { }

public static void main(String args[]) { }
```

EDIT (added this syntax from other contributors) :

```
public static void main(String... args) { }
```

Comment: This does not just apply to the main method, but to all other array definitions, too.

Comment: You forgot `public static void main(String... args)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, but the first is the prefered style.

**Edit:**
Another option is

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

which additionally allows callers to use varargs syntax.

Comment: (And `main(String... args)` is just freakish, although at least the syntax has some valid use cases.)

Comment: I disagree. The varargs syntax is finally a little less c-like. And that's a good thing.

Comment: There briefly was a variant with varargs, which disappeared so quickly it isn't even in the edit history.

Answer (score 10):

### Different Array notations

The notation

```
String args[]
```

is just a convenience for C programmers, but it's identical to this notation:

```
String[] args
```

Here's what the Sun Java Tutorial says:

> You can also place the square brackets
>   after the array's name:
>
> `float anArrayOfFloats[]; // this form is discouraged`
>
> However, convention discourages this
>   form; the brackets identify the array
>   type and should appear with the type
>   designation.

**Reference:** [Java Tutorial > Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

### VarArgs

BTW, a lesser known fact is that main methods also support varargs, so this is also okay:

```
public static void main(String ... args) { }
```

The reason is that a varargs method is internally identical to a method that supports a single array parameter of the specified type.E.g. this won't compile:

```
public static void main(final String... parameters){}
public static void main(final String[] parameters){}
// compiler error: Duplicate method main(String[])
```

**Reference:** [Java Tutorial > Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference, but the first one is according to standard.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are correct in that it doesn't make a difference. Let me just add two further points:

`String ... args` is also valid now and in this case again makes no difference.

The different options to place your brackets do have a consequence, when you define multiple variables. In the following example the variable `a` is not a String array, but `b` is one and `c` is an array of arrays of Strings.

`String a, b[], c[][];`

However, I have to suggest not to use this style for your code, as it can quickly become very confusing. For example, `String [] b, c[];` means the same for `b` and `c` as above, but especially for `c` this is non-obvious.

Comment: thanks for hurting my brain! I had to read this twice (just learning java)

Comment: Never declare multiple variables in one declaration, it is bad style and leads to confusion.

Answer (score 6):

No, they have no difference. Though... I used to use the second way, until my girlfriend threatened to break if I continued doing it (not kidding). So now I prefer the first way, and I think it looks much better.

Answer (score 4):

No, the above are equivalent. Arrays in Java can be declared in one of two ways, either:

```
String[] myarray;
```

or

```
String myarray[];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use String[] instead of use [] postfix to reference. Infact String[] obj; hilights the fact that obj is a reference of type String[] (array of String).

Answer (score 2):

I also prefer to mark the `args` as `final`.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a difference between the 2 choices you can do either one of them.

You could also put this:

```
public static void main(String... args) { }
```