# How can I return a statement in this program correctly?

Tags: java

I want my program to execute the first return statement if the conditions are true otherwise   return it as normal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();
        int answer = x + y;

        if (x == y) {
            System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);     
            return answer;
        }

        System.print.ln("These two numbers are not the same, but they equal: " + answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may check what `void` keyword is and when you have to use it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Your method is declared with a return type of `void`. In any case, this is your program's entry point. Where would the return value go?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to that return value?

Comment: Change the return type to `int`

Comment: @blgt: Then it won't be a valid `main()` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13603500/367273

Comment: @NPE I want the return value to print to the console if the "if" condition is not met. If the "if" condition is met, I want it to print what is inside the condition.

Comment: @NPE Yep you're right. I got stuck on the `void` and didn't get the to the `main` course

Comment: @ChristopherRene System.out.print prints to the console

Comment: @ChristopherRene Then you don't need to return the value. Just print it.

Comment: @NPE - It will be a perfectly valid method, just not valid as the main entry point of an application.

Comment: (To return a value from the main entry point, use `System.exit(answer);`.)

Comment: @HotLicks: We are splitting hairs. The Java Language Specification does not contain the words "entry point". The precise words that it uses for the concept we are discussing are "the main method" (see, for example, JLS 7 §12.1.4).

Comment: @NPE - But a method named "main" is not necessarily "the main method".

Comment: @HotLicks: Indeed. Again, we are splitting hairs. I think this whole debate is pretty pointless. ;)

Comment: @NPE - An important hair.  To return a value from "the main method" you use System.exit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your code you don't need to return anything. 
But, if you want to return something you are in the wrong method.

`main` is a "special" method, it cannot return anything (well, in other languages it might return an int which is the exit status, but ignore it here) and is where your code starts.

If you want to return something you should write a [`method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

A method is a block of code which is execute when you call it and can return value back to who called it. In this case your method will be static because you will call it from the `main` method which is static

```
public static int methodName()
{
    int X, Y;
    int answer;

    if (x == y)
    {
        // Do something
        return returnSomethingBackTomain;
    }
    else
    {
        return returnSomethingOfDifferentTomain;
    }
}
```

Well.. it could be your method

```
public static int methodName()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int y = input.nextInt();
    int answer = x + y;

    if (x == y) {
        System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("These two numbers are not the same, but they equal: " + answer);
    }
    return answer;
}
```

But please be more specific on what you want to do.
Because i dont see any reason to write a such method.

Answer (score 0):

If your main function is void, you don't have to return anything, you can just use

```
return;
```

That gives:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();
        int answer = x + y;

        if (x == y) {
            System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);     
            return;
        }

        System.print.ln("These two numbers are not the same, but they equal: " + answer);
    }
}
```

But you can also do:

```
    ...
        if (x == y) {
            System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);     
        } else {
            System.print.ln("These two numbers are not the same, but they equal: " + answer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a few mistakes.

The main method should never be used to return a value.
The main method is the entry point to your program.
Here you declare methods to be run at the start of the program. In GUI-projects, this is used to load the inital GUI (Forms).

Also, a void method cannot return something.
When initalising a method, you have to declare what type the returned value will have.
Void means that there is no data returned.

You will have to write a method which you can call to receive your data.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Untitled {

public int scanForEqualNumbers() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();
    int y = input.nextInt();
    int answer = x + y;

    if (x == y) {
        System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);     
        return answer;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Now you can initalize your class (e.g. *Scanner*) and call the method *scanForEqualNumbers*.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
int result = scanner.scanForEqualNumbers();
```

If you don't want to have to initialize a class to call the method, you can declare the *scanForEqualNumbers* as static.

```
public static int scanForEqualNumbers() { ...
```

Then you can call this method directly as this:

```
int result = Scanner.scanForEqualNumbers();
```

1 more note.
You don't need the return in the IF-statement.
As you return the answer anyway, you can keep the print the the IF-statement and use the return after it.
You could also return `-1` as answer in an ELSE-statement so you can use this answer in further methods. This way you can check the result of the method without having to read the console output.

I even suggest to make a seperate class for this.
You'll need your Main-method to run your program. This'll also be the location of your method class.

```
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyScanner myScanner = new MyScanner();
        int result = myScanner.scanForEqualNumbers();
        System.out.format("The scanned numbers %s equal", result > 0 ? "ARE" : "are NOT");
    }

}

public class MyScanner {
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Untitled {

    public int scanForEqualNumbers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();
        /* This can be replaced, see below
        int answer = x + y;

        if (x != y) {
            answer = -1;
        }

        return answer;
        */

        // IF X equals Y ? return X + Y : ELSE return -1
        return (x == y ? x + y : -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {}`?? This program isn't going to do anything...

Comment: @m0skit0 fixed it now

Comment: @GroundZero ternary if is more concise:  `x == y ? answer : -1`. Reassigning a temporary variable is not advised for readability and equal reasoning (you are reassigning `answer` to `-1`).

Comment: @Mik378 I know I could have used a ternary a.k.a. shorthand if-statement, but I though this would've been more readable. @Christopher you could also use `return (x == y ? answer : -1)` and you'd actually no longer need the `answer` variable. You could write this: `return (x == y ? x + y : -1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();
        int answer = x + y;

        if (x == y)
            System.out.println("These two numbers are the same and they equal: " + answer);     
        else
            System.print.ln("These two numbers are not the same, but they equal: " + answer);
    }
}
```

`main` has a `void` return type, so no need to return anything.

By the way, try to fit [CQS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) principle.
Indeed, **printing something is a side-effect operation**, so no need to return anything but `void`.