# Main method prototype, why are these working?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct Java main() method parameters syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089572/what-is-the-correct-java-main-method-parameters-syntax)

Why are these all working?

```
static void main(String[] args )

static void main(String args[] )

static void main(String... args )
```

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089572/544983

Comment: @DelShekasteh How did you find that one so fast? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any difference between them?

no difference just different representation

Answer (score 0):

No difference..

```
 String[] args; // This representation means that args is of String[] type(Basically array)

 String args[]; // This means that args is an array(an array of string type)

 String... args; // This means that args is a string of variable length(Thus acting as an array)
```

Comment: -1: `String... args` doesn't mean that args is a string of variable length. Fix this, and I will upvote instead.

Comment: i think i m misunderstood here...i am saying that the string contains different elements and no of elements is of variable length

Comment: Hmm, it seems like you don't really know what varargs are. Search for it. "varargs". It are arrays, but there is a different syntax for passing it as an argument.

Comment: sorry but there is no diference u just pass as many items of you want of the same type

Comment: I'll say exactly what I thought about what you wrote: `String... args` is not **a** string of variable length. It **is an array of strings**, using the varargs syntax. Arrays are always fixed in length. That is why they have a property `array.length`. However, when using the varargs syntax, it allows you to pass an array without having to write `new String[]{"string 1", anotherString}`.